# Как на GitHub форкнуть только старую ветку(branch)

Tags: git, github

На `GitHub` есть проект который я хочу форкнуть. Проект содержит 2 ветки(branches)
**master**
**old-cli**
Если нажать на ***`Fork`***, то форкаются обе ветки.
`Вопрос`: возможно ли форкнуть только ветку ***old-cli*** без **master**?

Comment: Что вам мешает удалить мастер после форка? Репозиторий форкнутый целиком ваш, делайте что хотите.

Comment: @Monk после форка  я не вижу такой возможности. Я нашёл как сменить ветку по умолчанию, но как удалить нужную ветку, не удаляя весь проект, я не вижу.

Comment: *git push -f origin :master* если мне не изменяет память. В новых версиях ещё *--delete* добавили.

Comment: А если веток 5000, не будешь же ради одной ветки 4999 удалять через сайт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось через сайт удалить не нужную ветку(branch) очень просто.
 Спасибо Monk за наводку.
Для этого нужно на главной странице проекта, который форкнули, нажать на `branches`, выбрать ветку по умолчанию(её не возможно будет удалить в этом статусе) для этого нажимаете `Change default branch`.
 На против остальных веток будет иконка `"корзины"`, нажимая на неё Вы удаляете не нужную ветку.